# How to extract exact value from this string with match and regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

Hi,

I have this string:

```
var referer = "https://example.net:3000/page?room=room2"
```

I want to get only what comes after `=room` no matter its position so I tried this:

```
var value = referer.match(/[?&;](.+?)=([^&;]+)/g);
```

but Im getting this `["?room=room2"]` whereas the expected output is just `2`. Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8fduhLep/

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: _"I want to get only what comes after `=room`"_  I guess you meant `room=`? Also everything that comes after `room=` would include other query parameters, eg: `room=xyz&foo=abc`, in this case you're asking for a result of `xyz&foo=abc`, since that comes _after_ `room=`?

Comment: if the url is `example.net/index.php?room=room34&something=something` the output should be `34`

Comment: I see now, makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substring` and `indexOf`:

```js
var referer = "https://example.net:3000/page?room=room2"

const res = referer.substring(referer.indexOf('=room') + 5) //add 5 to account for length of string
console.log(res)
```

If it's not the only parameter, you can parse the URL and get the value of the `room` parameter, then use the method above:

```js
var referer = "example.net:3000/page?room=room2&someotherquery=something"


var roomVal = new URL("https://example.net:3000/page?room=room2").searchParams.get('room')
const res = roomVal.substring(roomVal.indexOf('=room') + 5)
console.log(res)
```

With regex:

```js
var referer = "example.net:3000/page?room=room2&someotherquery=something"

const regex = /room=room(\w+)/g
const res = regex.exec(referer)[1]

console.log(res)
```

Comment: 5 means that the output can be only 5 characters or?

Comment: @CainNuke It's because the query (`=room`) is 5 characters, and `indexOf` will return the index of the *start* of the query.

Comment: ahh, I see. I got it now. It works but what if room is not the last query of the url? Like in https://example.net:3000/page?room=room2&someotherquery=something

Comment: it works, but wouldnt it be much shorter with regex?

Comment: @CainNuke Updated to use regex.

Answer (score 2):

** Updated **

If you would like the numbers that come after =room - this does it

```
let value = referer.match(/=room(\d+)/);
```

Yields

```
[
  '=room2',
  '2',
  index: 34,
  input: 'https://example.net:3000/page?room=room2',
  groups: undefined
]
```

A nicer solution is

```
let url = new URL(referer);
let roomNumber = url.searchParams.get('room').replace(/[^\d]+/,'');
```

Comment: nice but I only need the `2`.